# SQL Order of Conditions

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE price= 6000 AND price < 8000 OR price = 10000;
```

I have tested it out at it returns all the products which have the price of 6000 or 10000. However, I have tried doing some research on which order the statements are read in this case and could not find anything. I am struggling to understand it and cannot clearly set it up straight in my head.

What if the two conditions were reversed or what if we have multiple AND/OR conditions that are not separated by parentheses? How will the system interpret more than two conditions which are not delimited?

Comment: The entire `where` expression is a condition on the result set.  It evaluates to true.  How the database arrives at that is an unnecessary detail when using SQL.

Comment: Don't be "that guy" writing where clause without parentheses. While it's technically possible, everyone will hate you.

Comment: `AND` has a higher precendence than `OR`. It basically parallels in boolean algebra they are analogous to multiplication and addition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AND` takes precedence over `OR`. That means it will find all rows from two "groups":

- The ones with `price= 6000 AND price < 8000`.
- Plus the rows with `price = 10000`.

The first group will only select the ones with price = 6000, since the condition requires the price to be that specific value, and the condition `price < 8000` is discarded since it becomes redundant.

The second group will find rows with value 10000 (obviously).

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot because I could not understand if it would be interpreted as:`
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE (price= 6000 AND price < 8000) OR price = 10000;

or 

SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE price= 6000 AND (price < 8000 OR price = 10000);

Comment: @ElenaM. As the first option, since `AND` takes precedence over `OR`. In any case, if you are unsure, just add the parenthesis; be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite the `WHERE` clause in the way below,

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE (price between 6000 AND 8000) OR (price = 10000);
```

This will provide you the results of price between 6000 AND 8000 as well as 10000